# Content-Disposition for email body

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, content-disposition

As far as I understand Content-Disposition header can by userd for any body part of email message

> It specifies the    "Content-Disposition" header field, which is
> optional and valid for    any MIME entity ("message" or "body part")
>
> RFC 2183

I saw that many mail clients set Content-Disposition header only for attachmetns body parts.

The question is: is it normal to set Content-Disposition to inline for message body (text/html/email body) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "normal"?

It's acceptable to set Content-Disposition to "inline" for the message body, but as you noted most mailers only use Content-Disposition to set it to "attachment".  And setting it to "inline" generally doesn't make any difference to how a mailer is going to display the message.  That is, you can't force it to display some content inline if it doesn't know how to, or if only considers additional body parts as attachments.

Comment: Im actually interested in parsing incoming email with JavaMail API for analyzing message content. The question is how to differentiate message body and attachments with MIME type text/* ?
The original idea was to chek disposition value: if null and MIME type is like text/* than it is body. But now I see that disposition may be set not only to attachments, but for body also.

Comment: Have you seen [this JavaMail FAQ entry](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#mainbody)?

Comment: That's exactly how I process messages now. But, if I'm not mistaken, this won't work if one some text/* attachment will come before the body. But I suppose that means that this is an improperly formatted message.

Comment: That's not impossible per the MIME spec, but no real mailers will do that.